# Series calculation precision

Tags: python, precision, calculation

I need to find the sum of the first N elements of the series to satisfy some precision e (10^-3, for example):

**y = -(2x + (2x)^2/2 + (2x)^3/3 + ...)**

The exact sum of y is **log(1 - 2*x)**.

I wrote a program in python, but the difference W between sum and log turns out to be non-zero in case of set precision (the last significant digit is 1 or 2 in some samples).

```
from math import log

def y_func(x, e):
   y = 0
   nom = 2*x
   den = 1
   a = nom / den
   while abs(a) > e:
      y -= a
      den += 1
      nom *= 2*x
      a = nom / den
   return y

def main(p):
    print(('{:{width}}'*4).format('X','Y','Z','W',width = 14))
    prec = 10**-p
    x = -.25
    xk = .35
    h = .05
    while x <= xk:
       Y = y_func(x, prec)
       Z = log(1-2*x)
       W = Y - Z
       print(('{:<{width}.{prec}f}'*4).format(x, Y, Z, W, \
                                      prec = p, width = 14))
       x += h


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(3)
```

Comment: How did you derive your stopping condition, i.e. `while abs(a) > e`? Does it at all relate to the Lagrange error bound for the Taylor expansion you're using?

Comment: **a** is  a member of the sum **y** and as calculation proceeds the **a** is getting smaller and smaller untill it gets less then e. Yes

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this means that 3 digits after point must be the same and  therefore their difference is 0. But it isn't, no matter what e is set to.

Comment: Well, the fact that one particular term is smaller than e doesn't mean the overall sum has converged to within e of the true value.

Comment: Can you give some useful tips or information to read, I think I've missed some fundamentals or something. By the way,the task was to calculate terms untill it gets less then e. I believe I have an error because the other classmates have y - z  = 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well said [@NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe), unfortunately this still doesn't fix the problem.

I wanted to call your attention to the fact that such series does **not** converge fast enough to allow you to say that if `abs(a) < e` then `y`'s precision is `e`.

That means that even if you make your loop do that one more iteration you'll still have less (much less!) than `e` precision when `x` approaches `.50`.

To fix this once for all you should change your `while` to something like:

```
while abs(y - log(1-2*x)) >= e: # > or >= depending on what you need
    # y = ...
```

Comment: Right. This does defeat the purpose of the approximation though, since now to approximate you need to already know the true value. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping one iteration too early: you stop as soon as `nom / den` goes below the threshold, *but before you've subtracted it from `y`*.

In other words, you need to restructure your `while` loop.

Comment: That kind of worked, but doesn't this mean that the program calculates **a** that is less than **e** and subtracts it?